# RewriteRule doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to convert this url:

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category.php?cate=mens
```

to:

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category/cate/mens/
```

I have this rule, but it doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule category/cate/(.*)/ category.php?cate=$1
RewriteRule category/cate/(.*) category.php?cate=$1
```

Comment: are you sure your config is being picked up... if this is htaccess try throwing some garbage text in to see if apache is even try you parse it.

Comment: yes my .htaccess is working, i tried how you suggested

Comment: Which way are you trying to convert it? Your explanation goes from ?cate= to /cate/ and your code does the opposite...

Comment: @SamHuckaby to this form g2g/category/cate/(Any Value)/ i dont know what is failed

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located? Is it in the g2g folder?

Comment: yes in the g2g folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /g2g/

RewriteRule ^category/cate/(.+?)/?$ category.php?cate=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /g2g/category\.php\?cate=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /g2g/category/cate/%2?%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: how can i do to use this rule with multiples parameters and these parameters are optionals?

Comment: @EmilioGort just add another `(.+?)` before thre `$` and backreference it using a `$2`

Comment: thanks, i'm writting this RewriteRule ^category/(.+?)/?(.+?)$ category.php?cate=$1&sub=$2 [L] but cant get the second parameter

Comment: @EmilioGort you don't want the `/` to be optional there, so remove the `?`.

Answer (score 2):

Your rewrite is for the opposite direction. i.e. it **rewrites**

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category/cate/mens/
```

to:

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category.php?cate=mens
```

If what you want is to **redirect**

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category.php?cate=mens
```

to:

```
http://ts.thebenamorgroup.com/g2g/category/cate/mens/
```

Then you can use:-

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cate=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^g2g/category\.php$ /g2g/category/cate/%1/ [NC,R]
```